# Why Bootstrap lightbox thumbnail not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am following online tutorial for bootstrap lightbox thumbnail. I typed exact same code multiple times but it is not working. Whenever I click on the image, it opens up in new tab instead of popping up in the same window. 
Here is the code,

```
<title>Lightbox</title>

<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="F:/LightBox/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet"     src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
-->
<link rel="stylesheet"  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="1.jpg"="image=1" data-title="my CATioN"><img src="1.jpg"   alt="" class="img-thumbnail"</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--
<script src="F:/LightBox/lightbox.js"></script>
-->

</body>
```

I tried adding     lightbox.js file at different positions but, still not working.

Comment: Open the Chrome developer tools or Mozilla. There are errors?

Comment: Why you have two  `<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` ?

Comment: I was trying all possible ways. It won't work even if keep both of them or remove either. Chrome developer shows the error     lightbox.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your HTML:

1. Your `img` tag isn'g closed.
2. You have this inside your `a` tag `href="1.jpg"="image=1"`, just
   link to the image path once.
3. You aren't using the **data-attribute** for the plugin: 
   `data-lightbox=""` on your `a` tag either.

Review the Docs: [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Working Example

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.2/css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a class="img-thumbnail" href="http://placehold.it/350x350/f00" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="title">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/350x350/f00" alt="alt">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a class="img-thumbnail" href="http://placehold.it/350x350/000" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="title">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/350x350/000" alt="alt">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a class="img-thumbnail" href="http://placehold.it/350x350/ff0" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="title">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/350x350/ff0" alt="alt">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a class="img-thumbnail" href="http://placehold.it/350x350" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="title">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="alt">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.2/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you very much vanburen. I removed data-attribute as it was mentioned it is not important in the tutorial.